# Is there a way to use Coalesce in where clause using findoptions?

Tags: sql, typeorm

I'm relatively new to typeorm and am having some issues recreating one of our queries using FindOptions. I found a way to write it using typeorms QueryBuilder, but would like leverage some of the other functionality that typeorm offers when using their findOptions (such as the eager flag when defining entity relationships).

```
const sql = this.repository
      .createQueryBuilder('table1','t1')
      .where('COALESCE(t1.deleted_at, t1.updated_at, t1.created_at) >= :timestamp', {
        timestamp: timestamp,
      })
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples that relate to using coalesce in typeorm. Specifically, this is the part I can't seem to rewrite with findOptions

```
.where('COALESCE(t1.deleted_at, t1.updated_at, t1.created_at) >= :timestamp', {
        timestamp: timestamp,
      })
```

I tried something like

```
this.repository.find({
      where: Raw('COALESCE(t1.deleted_at, t1.updated_at, t1.created_at) >= :timestamp', {
        timestamp: timestamp,
      }),
```

but obviously that is not valid syntax, as Raw() expects the column alias. Hopefully this has adequately described my issue!

PS. I'm new to SO and will appreciate any feedback regarding how to improve the quality of my question(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently *TypeORM* does not have a `COALESCE` *operator* in find-where clause since (as you correclty wrote) it expects an alias.

You can trick *TypeORM* combining `where` clause and `Raw` (ignoring the alias with `_`) using a valid column.
See [this](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options) for more information.
However, this is a little bit confusing and not *purely* correct.

```js
const result = await this.repository.find({
  where: {
    created_at: Raw(_ => `COALESCE(deleted_at, updated_at, created_at) >= :timestamp`, { timestamp })
  }
});
```

The most correct approach is using **QueryBuilder**:

```
const result = await this.repository
  .createQueryBuilder('table1', 't1')
  .where('COALESCE(t1.deleted_at, t1.updated_at, t1.created_at) >= :timestamp', {
    timestamp: timestamp,
  })
  .getMany();
```

Comment: Thank you! That underscore was the piece I was missing. I accepted your answer but am curious how you determined the alias could be skipped. Even going back now knowing what to look for, I can't seem to find that in their docs. Regardless, thanks again!

Comment: See [this](https://imgur.com/a/W4rnQkP) image.
As you can see ```Raw``` accepts a function with a parameter called ```alias```.
```alias``` identifies the column in the current *where* clause and you can use it to *compose* the raw query.
In our case we don't need to use the alias so we skip it with ```_``` (tell Typescript compiler that we ignore the parameter).

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! I had no idea I could ignore parameters in TS via _. It makes sense why I never encountered that in the typeorm docs :D I appreciate it!